# Java regular expression to find occurence of a particular substring n times

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with alphabets followed by numbers(1-4). For example

```
String input = "A1 B1 P3 D1 D2 D3 D4 F3 F3 Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4 P2";
```

I want to find the strings which have an alphabet with all the 4 numbers (1 to 4) in consecutive manner. In above example, it is `D1 D2 D3 D4` or `Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4`.

Is there any possible way by which we can match this using RE in java?

Comment: Read the Javadoc tor `java.util.regex.Pattern` and study the "Back References" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with backreferences.

Here is an fully executable program:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Four {
    static String input = "A1 B1 P3 D1 D2 D3 D4 F3 F3 Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4 P2";
    static Pattern four = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])1 \\12 \\13 \\14");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher m = four.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs

```
D
Z
```

The regex you are looking for is

```
([A-Z])1 \\12 \\13 \\14"
```

It matches

- First, a capital A through Z
- Followed by a 1
- Then a space
- Then, `\1` a backreference, matches the contents of the string that were matched in the *first* set of parentheses. So if you previously had `D1`, the `\1` matches `D`.
- Next, the number 2
- (This continues to pick up the 3 and the 4).

You may wish to replace the single space with `\\s+`, meaning one or more space characters, if your use case allows it.

**EDIT**

The `group(1)` picks up the value matched within the parentheses. If you change this to `group(0)` you will pick up the entire matched string, and the program will then output

```
D1 D2 D3 D4
Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon.  Please explain your answer.

Comment: Yup, as you can tell by the non-indented answer, I hit submit prematurely. :) Appreciate the note, though, thanks.

Comment: can you print `D1 D2 D3 D4` , instead of D

Comment: Thanks @RayToal for letting me know the back reference concept

Comment: @yash Yes indeed! simply replace `group(1)` with `group(0)`

Comment: how group(0) and group(1)  differ in execution?

Comment: thanks. to know more about regex, refer the link pls @ray toal

Comment: @yash https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html